# Firebase + SSR billing

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I'm using a very basic Cloud Function to determine if the incoming request comes from a bot and deliver server rendered content if that's the case on an Angular app hosted on Firebase.

My understanding is that this function gets the HTML from Firebase hosting and then writes it manually to the response so the user can get it.

My question is: **Do i get charged twice for the traffic both in hosting and in functions?** Since the page is rendered on the hosting but then transferred first to the function which in turn sends it back to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time your function on Cloud Functions gets called, you pay for the time it is active. You also pay for the bandwidth of the response it sends.

Every time a URL is served from the Firebase Hosting CDN, you pay for the bandwidth that is used to serve that response.

If a hit to a URL leads to a call to Cloud Functions, you will pay both for the bandwidth from Cloud Functions, and the bandwidth from the CDN to the user.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply Frank! Do you know if it possible to do different rewrites based on user-agent using Hosting rules?